# Recommendation for a light duty screwdriver with a precise clutch

Tags: tools, screwdriver

I've scoured the web looking for info on a good light duty screwdriver with a precise clutch but I cant sift through all the bs.  I have a Milwaukee fuel m12 drill/driver which is great for the heavier duty tasks but I need something for smaller tasks. The main characteristic I'm looking for is a good clutch with many positions which can go low enough for working on small sensitive applications like electronics.  Real assembly tools seem to be mostly pnuematic and very expensive, but I don't need that level of precision(at those prices at least) Suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is essentially a shopping question, which is off-topic here.

Comment: use a manual screwdriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request for a "precise" clutch would appear to indicate a "torque screwdriver" which are widely available in "manual-operated" form but which can, due to precision (and probably low sales volume as well) be fairly expensive. I have a Sturtevant/Richmont torque screwdriver (purchased used) for that purpose. There are others...

Looking for those characteristics in a power-tool form is both overkill for any use other than an assembly line and even more expensive. For most things where you just need to assemble without destroying, learning to use a manual screwdriver is all that's required. The Torque screwdriver is for things like electrical connectors that have a specified torque range that needs to be hit with some precision.